# Usage of "as much ... as"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Consumers spend three times as much paying rent as buying books.

How can I understand this sentence?

I believe "three times as much + noun + as" and "spend + noun + doing" are very common, but in the case above, a noun seems missing.

Comment: The "missing noun" is simply that in such contexts we don't need to repeat the subject and verb before the second "object". Which would give *Consumers spend three times as much paying rent as **consumers spend** buying books.* Note that in practice nobody normally uses that "full" form, but it's common (though not *necessary*) to repeat the reference to the subject using a pronoun... *Consumers spend three times as much paying rent as **they spend** buying books.* It's a bit verbose anyway, compared to *Consumers spend three times as much **on** rent as **[on]** books.*

Comment: Just as the object of _eat_ can only be food, the object of _spend_ can only be money. So such questions as _Have you eaten yet?_ don't need to specify the object, and the same applied to _spend_: _I spent a lot there, but he didn't_ is perfectly grammatical and nothing's missing.

Comment: @JohnLawler: But apart from the rather unusual context many years ago when Viv Nicholson said she was gonna [Spend, spend, spend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viv_Nicholson) after a big football pools win, we don't usually use ***to spend*** "intransitively". I assume *I spent a lot* and *I ate a lot* count as *transitive* usages, but whereas intransitive ***I ate this morning*** is fine, ***I spent this morning*** is decidedly weird!

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, In think Fumblefingers is right there.  In "I spent a lot", the phrase 'a lot' is, on the most likely reading, a direct object as opposed to an adjunct of frequency.

Comment: There's also the metaphorical _spend_ of _spend time_, from [the _`TIME` Is `MONEY`_ metaphor theme.](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf)

Comment: "Much" is best analysed as a fused determiner-head NP., understood as "much money". The fusion involves the determiner "much" and the understood head "money", which combine (or fuse) to give the single word "much".

Answer (score 1):

The nouns are not missing.  They are **gerunds**.  That is, the "paying" and "buying" are functioning as nouns in this sentence.

If they were broken up, they could be

> Consumers spend 3 times N paying rent

> Consumers spend N buying books.

Or compressed into the observation

> Consumers spend three times as much paying rent as buying books.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I'd expect it to be written like this:

Consumers spend three times as much ON paying rent as ON buying books.

I think that's why something seems to be missing.

As soon as you add the 'on', it is easy to understand.

It may be that in American English it is more stylistically likely for the ON to be omitted.

Comment: Why can’t you say: *Puzzlers spend three times as much ON doing crosswords as ON solving cyphers.* (where it is time being spent)?

Comment: The missing word is what they're spending three times as much of: money. As the comments say, this is understood.

Comment: I think it's better to say that "much" is a 'fused' determiner-head NP, understood as "much money". The fusion involves the determiner "much" and the understood head "money", which combine (or fuse) to give the single word "much".

Comment: You can say that, at least in British English, @TinfoilHat

Comment: I tire, of comments, that are not actually answers... @Barmar

Comment: @Jelila Tire? You should be grateful for members who take the time to help you, even if it's just in comments.

Comment: I’m not talking about comments to help me, @BillJ . I'm referring to unanswered questions, with tons of useful info in the comments, but nobody writing an actual answer.